# Memory leak in multi-threaded C++ application on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory-leak-detector

We have a big multi-threaded C++ application running on Linux. We see that occupied by the application memory grows fast and believe there are some leaks. We have tried every tool we have (valgrind, DynLeak, Purify) but did not find anything. Since this application can run on Windows, we have also tried Bounds Checker. Did not help, too.

We need a new tool that can help. I've looked at Google Perfomrance Tools, MMGR by Paul Nettle, MemCheck Deluxe. None of them impressed me.

Is there anywhere a good tool for this task?

Comment: If the above tools can't find a leak what makes you believe there is one?  Your app could just be using all the memory.  Or perhaps, your app is holding on to memory even though it is not using it.  For the last case, there would be no leak but just inefficient memory use or cleanup.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2007/11/29/tools-for-detecting-memory-leaks.aspx) can help. But how can you be sure that there's a memory leak, if no leak was detected using the other tools?

Comment: The leak may be in a third party library or perhaps you are simply seeing the results of resource pools and other caches in your application or even the OS ... large memory use is not a sign of a memory leak necessarily. See if it continually grows over time under the same load.

Comment: 1. We believe that there are leaks as we see that memory occupied by this applicaation grows all the time.

Comment: 2. This is a mature application using the same 3rd pary tools for couple of years. I believe that if the leaks were caused by those tools we could have seen them earlier. This is not a case. This is something new.

Answer (score 5):

The definition of a memory leak in C/C++ is very specific: it is memory that has been allocated and then the pointer was overwritten or otherwise lost. Valgrind generally detects such cases out of the box, but things are not always that simple.

- Your application could very well be still using that memory. In that case you might have what a *Java* programmer would consider a leak, e.g. entering data in a structure and rarely (or never) removing entries.
- You might be measuring the memory usage of your memory incorrectly. On Linux memory usage measurements are not as straight-forward as they seem. How have you measured your memory usage?
- You should consider using the application hooks (Valgrind calls them [client requests](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.clientreqs)) of whatever memory analysis tool your are using, to avoid the issue with reports only being issued at program termination. Using those hooks might help you pin-point the location of your leak.
- You should try using a heap profiler, such as [massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html) from Valgrind, to look for memory allocation locations with inordinate amounts of allocated memory.
- Make sure you are not using a custom allocator or garbage collector in your application. As far as I know, no memory analysis tool will work with a custom allocator without [user interference](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mempools).
- If your memory leak is massive enough to be detectable within an acceptable amount of application run-time, you could try a binary search of old revisions through your version control system to identify the commit that introduced the problem. At least [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#bisect)
  and [Git](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) offer built-in support for this task.

Answer (score 2):

If by "did not help" you mean it did not report memory leaks, it is quite possible you don't have one and just use more and more memory that is still referenced by pointers and can be deleted.

Comment: Unfortunately, we do have something. The application started behaving like this just couple of months ago after unidentified changes. This is the reason we are looking for leaks.

Comment: @Michael: Have your tried a bisection search through your version control system to identify the commit that caused the leak?

Comment: I wish  it was feasible. We have several tens of developers working on the application.

Comment: @Michael: Err... why does that affect your ability to perform a binary search?

Comment: The number of changes is too big. Most of them are tightly coupled. We just cannot split changes into independent groups to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To help you debug the problem, perhaps in your logging, you should also write memory size, number of objects (their type) and a few other stats which are useful to you. At least until you become more familiar with the tools you mentioned.

Comment: +1 for in-application logging/debugging code. In one of my applications I had to check for memory leaks on Windows. Having no tool at my disposal for that platform at the time, I wrote a wrapper around `malloc()` and `free()` that kept track of all memory allocations and releases. A rather extreme solution, but it worked!

Comment: I agree with you and have proposed that to our manager. Still, I would like to find a proven tool for this job. Your way is very complex and tiresome. We will take it if nothing helps, though.